# Writing a Matlab script to implement a changing sum

Tags: matlab, programming

I am trying to implement this computation in Matlab, but I don't know how.

I want to compute the following:

$$p(k,j) = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=j+1}^{k} x_{i-1}}{\sum\limits_{i=j+1}^{k}(y_{i-1} - y_i)}$$ where $j = 0,\ldots,k-1$. For example for $k = 2$, $j = 0,1$. Thus,

$$ p(2,0) =  \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2}x_{i-1}z_{i-1}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^2 (y_{i-1}-y_i)} \quad \text{and} \quad p(2,1)  = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=2}^{2}x_{i-1}z_{i-1}}{\sum\limits_{i=2}^2 (y_{i-1}-y_i)} $$

For $k=3$, $j=0,1,2$ and 
$$p(3,0) = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}x_{i-1}z_{i-1}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 (y_{i-1}-y_i)}\,,p(3,1) =\frac{\sum\limits_{i=2}^{3}x_{i-1}z_{i-1}}{\sum\limits_{i=2}^3 (y_{i-1}-y_i)} \,, p(3,2) =\frac{\sum\limits_{i=3}^{3}x_{i-1}z_{i-1}}{\sum\limits_{i=3}^3 (y_{i-1}-y_i)} ~.$$

I have the values of $x$ and $y$ but I only have the initial value of $z$, $z_0$. The next value of $z$ is found iteratively: $$z_i = z_{i-1} - 1/p(k,j). $$

Comment: What does initial value of $z$ mean? Only $z_0$?

Comment: Yes, only $z_0$. The next value of z depends on the $p(k,j)$.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: You could notice that ${\sum\limits_{i=j+1}^{k}(y_{i-1} - y_i)}=y_j-y_k$

Comment: @JonasDahlbæk The question is how to implement in Matlab.

Comment: If the question had to do with what you've worked out in the question post, it's on topic here.   Questions about how to implement in Matlab, other software, etc.  then your question is off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab has one-based array indexing: x(1), x(2) and so on. You need to take it into account. If p(k,j) is two-dimensional array, then you need to change indexing too.

Let:
x_(i+1) = x(i), y_(i+1) = y(i), z_(i+1) = z(i), p_(k+1,j+1) = p(k,j)

So, $p(k,j)$ is calulated, using element-wise multiplication **.***, difference and vector sum operations, with this code:

```
p_(k+1,j+1) = sum(x_(j+1:k).*z_(j+1:k))/sum(y_(j+1:k)-y_(j+2:k+1))
```

One more hint, MATLAB has built-in function **diff**, calculating difference of neighbour elements. diff(X), for a vector X, is [X(2)-X(1)  X(3)-X(2) ... X(n)-X(n-1)]. So we can write:

```
p_(k+1,j+1) = sum(x_(j+1:k).*z_(j+1:k))/sum(-diff(y_(j+1:k+1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would I need a for loop?

Comment: Yes you need, because your variable $z_i$ is calculated iterative way. I do not know equation for $z_i$, probably you need a nested loop for $j$ and $k$.

Comment: Thanks. I gave the equation for $z_i$ as $z_i = z_{i-1} - 1/p(k,j)$.